# Mysql 5.0 LAST_INSERT_ID() differs after upgrading to 5.6

Tags: mysql, triggers, lastinsertid

Migrating from MySQL 5.0 to 5.6 i noticed that the INSERT_LAST_ID() function behaves different when using inside a trigger.

My simplified situation:

Table A has a (after insert) trigger: insert into table_B (ID) values(LAST_INSERT_ID());

Table B has the foreignkey: CONSTRAINT table_B FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Table_A (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT

This trigger-foreignkey combination works fine under 5.0 After migrating to 5.6 these triggers have other behavior.

Now the function LAST_INSERT_ID() used in the trigger seems to get a 0 (zero) and the second time the Primarykey-1.

I already searched the web but don't get any further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, 5.0 behavior is unlike 5.1 or higher. The recommendation would apply the following change to the after trigger:

```sql
-- insert into table_B (ID) values(LAST_INSERT_ID());
insert into table_B (ID) values (NEW.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this works like a charm, although its a bit strange the LAST_INSERT_ID function behaves different.

Comment: @user3415259: Yes, very strange behavior. I opened a bug report [Bug #76715](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76715).